# Bootstrap affix issue

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

When affixing a nav down the side of a page the content moves under the nav after initial scroll instead of staying along side, any ideas how to fix this?

Using:

```
data-spy="affix"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cooltrooper/eJFaY/3/

Thanks

Comment: 17 errors, 8 warnings when I try to validate the code (?) Adding </div></div></div> somehows give a result http://jsfiddle.net/davidkonrad/46ttD/

Comment: @davidkonrad its only a snippet from a larger page, so im not surprised it doesn't validate, but your fiddle still doesn't behave as it should, ie like it does on the oficial bootstrap docs. Thanks though

Answer (score 4):

I think you generally have to specify it to an element that doesn't have the `span*` class.
It works better if you add it to the `ul` :

```
<ul class="well nav nav-list" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
```

or

```
<ul class="well nav nav-list affix">
```

Comment: It does work better, but there is a size change using this method which would be hard to fix and maintain a responsive design...

Comment: It is not hard to fix. 
`ul {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I overcame this issue by adding CSS that applied to the element once the `"affix"` class is applied.

```
#your_element_id .affix {
top: (enter the pixel number where you want your element to stick);
}
```

Another option is to skip the `data-spy'affix'`. Attach the `"affix"` class inline.

Hopefully that provides some insight.